# Create a cauchy distribution histogram with a lower and an upper limit

Tags: python, scipy

I would like to simulate the following Lorentzian distribution with a histogram

*/<sub>2π</sub>*
*L* = ————————
      *(E − E<sub>0</sub>) + 0.25  <sup>2</sup>*

I found the  `scipy.stats.cauchy` and would like to truncate the distribution at a lower and an upper limit like so:

```
L = cauchy.rvs(size=300, loc = 5, scale =2.5, limits = [0,15] )
```

Is it possible?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Note that this is a Q&A site and not a code writing service. See also [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: StackOverflow does not support Latex rendering. I have updated your question to use normal text. But please update as said in comment above.

Comment: Should the term in the denominator be `(E - E0)**2`?  Cf. [Lorentzian function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LorentzianFunction.html).

Comment: yes, it should be `(E - E0)^2`. thanks everyone

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot add `limits` to the `rvs` method. As far as I know, only the `truncnorm` can do that. What you can do is either clip the values using `scipy.clip` (or `numpy.clip`) or filter the values outside your limits using a mask.

The first method will create a lot of 0s and 15s:

```
import scipy as sp
L = sp.clip(cauchy.rvs(size=300, loc = 5, scale =2.5), 0, 15)
```

The second will be randomly distributed in your interval:

```
import scipy as sp
L = cauchy.rvs(size=10000, loc = 5, scale =2.5), 0, 15)   #create a larger set to filter it out
L = L[sp.logical_and(L<15,L>0)][:300]
```